# Make a melt data to one

Tags: r

Having data like this:

```
doc_id sentence_id token_id     token     lemma  pos entity
text1           1        1       the       the  DET       
text1           1        2       boy       boy NOUN       
text1           1        3        's        's PART       
text1           1        4      cars       car NOUN       
text1           1        5       are        be  AUX       
text1           1        6 different different  ADJ       
text1           1        7    colors     color NOUN
```

How is it possible to take the value of column doc_id and weither is the same example text1 merge the results of lemma column into one row separated by a single space

Example of expected output

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1), text = c("the boy's car be different color"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: This is probably a duplicate: `aggregate(lemma ~ doc_id, data = df1, paste, collapse = " ")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this question was asked before but I cannot find it right now so here it goes.

```
res <- aggregate(lemma ~ doc_id, df1, paste, collapse = " ")
res
#  doc_id                             lemma
#1  text1 the boy 's car be different color
```

**Data**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
doc_id sentence_id token_id     token     lemma  pos.entity
text1           1        1       the       the  DET       
text1           1        2       boy       boy NOUN       
text1           1        3        \'s        \'s PART       
text1           1        4      cars       car NOUN       
text1           1        5       are        be  AUX       
text1           1        6 different different  ADJ       
text1           1        7    colors     color NOUN  
", header = TRUE)
df1[] <- lapply(df1, trimws)
df1[3, 4:5] <- paste0("'", df1[3, 4:5])
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(doc_id) %>%
   summarise(lemma = str_c(lemma, collapse = ' '))
# A tibble: 1 x 2
#  doc_id lemma                            
#  <chr>  <chr>                            
#1 text1  the boy 's car be different color
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(doc_id = c("text1", "text1", "text1", "text1", 
"text1", "text1", "text1"), sentence_id = c("1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1"), token_id = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"
), token = c("the", "boy", "'s", "cars", "are", "different", 
"colors"), lemma = c("the", "boy", "'s", "car", "be", "different", 
"color"), pos.entity = c("DET", "NOUN", "PART", "NOUN", "AUX", 
"ADJ", "NOUN")), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```